# How do Git hosting services like GitHub or GitLab store and serve all versions of files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

One of GitHub's useful features is that it serves various views of a single file. For example, if we take a single file,

1. A snapshot of the file in a commit: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5c8f4817500313a8b942ac9e189248f1077272f8/index.html
2. A version in a branch: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/gh-pages/index.html

and so on...

Basically GitHub/GitLab has a page for every file for every snapshot.

I'm wondering how this is implemented in the backend. Do they store and index every snapshot individually so they can be served quickly? Or do they load them in realtime? If they're storing every file's every snapshot, it feels a bit inefficient storage-wise.

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Really don't understand hostility. I can edit the question format if you want. I've googled and couldn't find info on this anywhere, and thought it would be useful for anyone interested in how these git hosting services work.

Comment: GitLab is [open source](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab) so you can investigate the source code. But you can view every tracked file in any commit in a git repository without checking them out to local feilsystem using `git show revision:/path/to/file`, e.g. `git show HEAD:.gitignore`

Comment: @phd yes I am aware of the git commands, but just curious how massive hosting services like GitHub and GitLab work. I was assuming they don't do these operations in realtime, but the only other option I could think of is to actually store every snapshot of every file, which raises the storage efficiency question. I thought about looking into the GitLab repo but it's a bit overwhelming, so thought I would ask here first. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure they store Git objects in a huge database and use modified `libgit` to access the database. They reimplement `git` commands on top of said modified `libgit`.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub stores Git data in a normal Git repository.  When Git data is needed to render a page of any sort, an RPC request for the appropriate type of data is made to the file server and the data is returned, and then it is highlighted (if necessary) and rendered.  GitHub uses many advanced features of Git to provide the most efficient access to data possible.

There are many types of RPC calls that can provide different types of data for different types of pages and other services that need them to operate (like the GPG verification service).  These RPC calls use either Git or libgit2 to acquire and process the data.

The file servers and the web frontends exist in the same datacenter on powerful servers with fast connections and generally the performance impact of doing things this way is minimal.